# How to run some SQL commands on Drupal 7 User Rregistration

Tags: drupal

I need to run a SQL command right after a new user account has been created (I need to obtain new User ID also). (in Drupal 7)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In a custom drupal module, use [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7).

within that function the $account variable with have the new user data and user id number.

To run custom sql query, you can use drupal's [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) function.

If you need to learn about custom drupal module development, take a look at the [example modules.](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)

Answer (score 0):

Build a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360) with [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) implementation.

Here's a code sample that saves the new user's id into a table called `test_table`.

```
function [YOUR_MODULE]_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {

    $newUserId = $account->uid;
    db_insert('test_table')
        ->fields(array(
            'user_id' => $newUserId,
        ))
        ->execute();
}
```